# Deck.GL React Scatterplot Layer animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, deck.gl

I have been following the below tutorial on custom animations within Deck.GL, I have converted this over to a react format and can make everything display but seem unable to correctly update the layers during the animation - any help would be greatly appreciated!

The function animateLibraries (line - 114) successfully creates the delay factor and the revised layers but these layers are not rendered through the process. Therefore what is rendered is the original layer with an animation progress value of 0 - meaning nothing will show.

I have tried updating the state but seemingly no avail - so how can I correctly render the revised layers on their creation.

Tutorial:
https://peterbeshai.com/blog/2019-08-10-deckgl-point-animation/

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-deckgl-animation-y9954?file=/src/scatterplot.jsx

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some more details about the problem? Perhaps where in the code you suspect it may be caused and any attempted solutions.

Comment: I have implemented a similar approach of animation using deck.gl and remotion. It can be similar to your use case.
https://github.com/alexfernandez803/animate-deck-gl

Answer (score 0):

**GPU-based data filtering** is highly recommended. You can take a look at this extension [DataFilterExtension](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/extensions/data-filter-extension). That's an alternative to filtering the data array on the CPU, like your example.

[Live](https://deck.gl/examples/data-filter-extension/) and [code](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/8.3-release/examples/website/data-filter/app.js) example.

There are [limitations](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/extensions/data-filter-extension#limitations) in some layers though.